# Angular 2 Typescript in limited IDE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are developing web applications in a **very basic IDE**. Basically it is closer to a text editor than a development environment. However, we are stuck with it.

Currently we are using Angular v1.5 for development of all our web applications. I am looking into the possibility to go for v2.
The first choice is TypeScript VS JavaScript. It seems like Google is somewhat pushing TypeScript as the preferred method. It offers extra checks and the support for TypeScript (documentation etc..) seems to be better than JavaScript. So I am hoping to get started with TypeScript.

My question: it seems like using TypeScript requires the sources to be transpiled to JavaScript. With tools like NodeJS. However, our IDE does not provide such functionality. Doing this outside the IDE and importing the JS would be too much work. I cannot imagine we are the only ones stuck to a simple development environment.

Are there any options to make use of Angular 2.0 TypeScript for us? As the support for versions 1.x will be removed, we really want to get started with this. Or should we go with JavaScript? I am afraid it will be more difficult to find support online.

Comment: What do you mean by `importing the JS`?  Import it into what?

Comment: What is the IDE you are using? Is there a option to switch to different IDE, it need not to be an IDE as such simple sublime should be enough. Apart from that transpiling is not actually a feature of IDE but a feature of runtime i.e the module you use for it.

Comment: Its an SAP product. The repository where your code is stored provides the text editor where you write the code. Or import a resource file from your local PC.

Comment: Oh that's a nightmare.  So you would have to work on your TypeScript in a separate editor, use node to build it, and then upload the compiled JS into SAP.  I can see why you wouldn't want to do that.  Any chance you could automate the upload into SAP, to run at the end of your build?

Comment: @BuhBuh Thanks, that's what I thought. And unfortinately SAP products don't allow much flexibility when it comes to this stuff so I guess were stuck with V1.5 until the provide us some built-in tools.
Also not sure why this legit question is being downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Width this approach - small IDE and no automatisation you will be unable to develop angular2 apps anyway. It uses alot of new es6 features which is not supported everywhere, so you need to transpile you code.

I recommend you to use TypeScript as it's native angular realisation and syntax is suitable.

Usual method is to use task runner or module bundler like webpack and import modules in preferred syntax. Like this.

```
import { foo } from 'baz'
```

Doesn't look as much work?

If you use this approach you could get some TypeScript benefits, even width your small IDE. Compiler will throw you errors and warnings, and transpile everything to preferred ES version.

And you will need some automatisation anyway, event with plain JS, if you want to use ES6 features. Which is vital width angular2. So you either need to switch IDE or use node.